# Why when using scipy's freqz on a firwin filter we get a limited frequency resolution?

Tags: python, filter, scipy, signals, signal-processing

I have recently been working with data sampled at high sampling rates (1M and higher)

I am trying to write an efficient polyphase filter, (based on the code seen [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/kastnerkyle/kastnerkyle.github.io/blob/master/posts/polyphase-signal-processing/polyphase-signal-processing.ipynb))

My decimation rates are close to 10000, and so the Nyquist frequency to filter around is ~100Hz

After some debugging, I realized that when representing my filter taps using scipy.signal.freqz the resolution is limited at approx 1000 Hz, this does not change when increasing the fir filter order.

I couldn't find any documentation on the issue, how could I observe my filter with higher resolution?

Comment: minimal, reproducible example would help us help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution of [`scipy.signal.freqz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqz.html) is limited by the number of frequency points `worN` through the formula `fs/2/worN` for half-spectrum (or `fs/worN` for full-spectrum). Since `worN` is by default 512, with your signal sampled at 1MHz you'd get a resolution of approximately 1000000Hz/2/512 ~ 1000.

To increase the resolution of `freqz` on your `filterCoefficients` (in your case obtained by `firwin`), simply increase `worN`. For example with something like:

```
w,h = freqz(filterCoefficients, worN=2048, fs=fs)
```